# How to select a selected value from database in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to make a select that will help me in my "edit user" page.
I have this code but I don´t know how to change it so I can load the value selected from the database.
This code it´s working...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <th><label for="text">Tipo Sanguineo:</label></th>
    <td><select class="form-control" id="sangue" name="tipo_sangue">
    <option value="O-" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "O-") echo 'selected';?> >O-</option>
    <option value="O+" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "O+") echo 'selected';?> >O+</option>
    <option value="A-" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "A-") echo 'selected';?> >A-</option>
    <option value="A+" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "A+") echo 'selected';?> >A+</option>
    <option value="B-" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "B-") echo 'selected';?> >B-</option>
    <option value="B+" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "B+") echo 'selected';?> >B+</option>
    <option value="AB-" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "AB-") echo 'selected';?> >AB-</option>
    <option value="AB+" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == "AB+") echo 'selected';?> >AB+</option>
</select></td>
  </div>
```

I need to do this with this code:

```
<?php $dts = DBRead11(); ?>
<select name="diretor_turma" id="diretor_turma" required class="input-field4">
  <?php
    foreach($dts as $option) {
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option['nome']; ?>"><?php echo $option['nome']; ?></option>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

The code that I need to change is loading the values from the database to the site, and Im not sure how to see the selected one if I load them from the database.

Comment: Add the `if`-statement to the new code as well, but change it to: `if ($cl_tipo_sangue == $option['nome'])`. The only difference here is really that you use `$option['nome']` instead of your hard coded values.

Comment: The selected one would still be `$cl_tipo_sangue`

Comment: This are differente codes.. the first one is the example and the second one is the one that I want to work, but don´t know how..

Comment: there is no selected attribute in second code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php $dts = DBRead11(); ?>
<?php $cl_tipo_sangue = "B+"; ?>// here you need to add db value which you saved in DB
<select name="diretor_turma" id="diretor_turma" required class="input-field4">
  <?php
    foreach($dts as $option) {
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option['nome']; ?>" <?php if ($cl_tipo_sangue == $option['nome']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> ><?php echo $option['nome']; ?></option>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I don´t want to use my first code... it was just an example.. I want to do on the second one what is on the first..

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1) Take an array to save drop down options' id name pairs.

2) Loop over it in the `<select>` tag for `<option>`s.

3) Check if selected id is the current iteration id.

4) If yes, add attribute `selected="selected"` to current `<option>`

And check in the loop if selected one.

```
<?php
$bloodGroups = [
'O-' => 'O-',
'O+' => 'O+',
'A-' => 'A-',
'A+' => 'A+',
'B-' => 'B-',
'B+' => 'B+',
'AB-' => 'AB-',
'AB+' => 'AB+'
];
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <th><label for="text">Tipo Sanguineo:</label></th>
    <td><select class="form-control" id="sangue" name="tipo_sangue">
    <?php
    if (! empty($bloodGroups)) {
     foreach ($bloodGroups as $bgid => $bloodGroup) {
      $selected = ($cl_tipo_sangue == $bgid) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
?>
<option value="<?php echo $bgid;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $bloodGroup;?></option>
<?php
     }
    }
    ?>
</select></td>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don´t want to use my first code... it was just an example.. I want to do on the second one what is on the first..

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript

```
<?php $dts = DBRead11(); ?>
<select name="diretor_turma" id="diretor_turma" required class="input-field4">
  <?php
    foreach($dts as $option) {
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option['nome']; ?>"><?php echo $option['nome']; ?></option>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#diretor_turma').value = '<?= $cl_tipo_sangue ?>'
</script>
```

Comment: I don´t want to use my first code... it was just an example.. I want to do on the second one what is on the first..

Comment: @Donutsrool You can see that i already used the second code only

Comment: Negative.. you used the first one part on the script "cl_tipo_Sangue"

Comment: @Donutsrool because you don't mention the equivalent to `cl_tipo_Sangue` in second code

Answer (score 0):

> You need to fetch the value you saving in database then

```
 <?php
  $nome = $database_value;

?>
<select name="diretor_turma" id="diretor_turma" required class="input-field4">
  <?php
    foreach($dts as $option) {
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option['nome']; ?>" <?php echo ($option['nome'] == $nome)?'selected':'' ?>><?php echo $option['nome']; ?></option>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="diretor_turma" id="diretor_turma" required class="input-field4">
        <?php 
        foreach($dts as $option) {
            $select = (isset($cl_tipo_sangue) && $cl_tipo_sangue == $option['nome'])?"selected = 'selected'":"";?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option['nome']; ?>"  <?php echo $select; ?>><?php echo $option['nome']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```